# Javascript: normalize argument in a function, should I copy it?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, normalization

Let's say there is a function:

```
const foo = (arg) => { do_something };
```

Before I run `do_something`, I actually want to normalize `arg` to an array because the function accept string or types other than array.

I know it is a bad practice to directly modify the passed argument in a function because it may be mutated and resulted in bugs, which are hard to be debugged. So, I will do something like this:

```
const foo = (arg) => {
  const _arg = Array.isArray(arg) ? [...arg] : [arg];
  do_something(_arg)
};
```

As above, I actually do a shallow copy of that array(`arg`), and use `_arg` to do something afterward, and I will ensure not to mutate it (since it just a shallow copy). My question is what if I just don't copy it?  i.e.:

```
const foo = (arg) => {
  const _arg = Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg];
  do_something(_arg)
};
```

Will it be different?  Or which one is a better/healthier way of coding?  Will it affect the garbage collecting or any performance issue?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Rule of thumb: No mutation = no copying necessary. However, your `do_something` is very limited. All it knows is that `_arg` is an array of something `[?]`. As a result it can only perform array operations that do not need to know anything about the elements' type, like `slice`, `concat` etc.

Comment: Yes, I only want to do array options at this moment, I may do `_array.filter(ele => typeof ele === ‘function’)` in `do_something` to ensure I will only have a collection of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the first approach is recommended, because the second approach often leads to the unexpected issues if `do_something` causes some side effects.

Will it affect garbage collecting? Yes. With the first approach, `_arg` will be cleaned because nothing references to it. I'm not sure about performance. It depends on the size of data you handle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: 1. It that says I should make a deep clone?!  Because a shallow copy is not guaranteed anything... 2. Just want to clarify, If I do not return `_arg` in the function, then it becomes garbage collectable right (the meaning of no reference)?! Sorry, I did not fully understand JS garbage collecting yet...

Comment: 1. Yes, at least for given case. Otherwise, it's hard to answer. Sometimes we don't need to make the program more complicate.
2. Yes. JS GC uses "Reference-counting" and "Mark-and-sweep" algorithms. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Answer (score 2):

My two cents on your concern is that in a language where there's no immutability by default, I would stick with coding conventions rather than trying to emulate immutability.

That is, if you state that arrays mustn't be modified and if a new element should be *pushed* or replaced you need to use `Array.prototype.concat` or *array spread operator*, I believe that your code will be simpler and easier to follow and maintain.

Also, you might want to use immutable collections like ones provided by [*ImmutableJS*](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: Yeah, I believe so, but sometimes it is hard to do.  Especially when I work on Node/Express. I have to mutate `res` object in order to keep middleware working. So hardly stick on the immuting preference of array sometimes makes it hard to code?! But than your from your answer that I know I should establish a consistent way in handling my codes!  I think I will follow the rule of thumb mentioned in previous comments, and makes the code less complicated if possible.

Comment: @LeoLi So, at the end of the day, you can mix pure FP with mutability. I'm struggling with the same issue of `Response` object from Express, but I got used to don't try to mutate arrays, objects... Now that we already have both array and object property spread operators, it's easier to follow the rule and produce elegant code!